# How to search colors when colors are stored as hexadecimal or RGB value?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, search

Background:

We are using [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision) to detect color properties from an image. The color values are stored as RGB values in the database. We want the user's to search for colors in our web application.

Scenario:

I want users to be able to search for colors or choose colors from the dropdown. The results would be shown on the page. But as far as I know, we can make a search feature by using text or numbers.

Database:

I am using firebase firestore and firebase-admin on the server-side. I am getting responses for colors as RGB values. I am storing RBG values for colors in the database.

The question is how can we make a search using RGB values or hex's values?

**Update 1:**

Example: 
1: The user uploads an image, colors extracted and stored in firestore. 
2: So, If the user wants to search he will type red, green, blue, etc. There are only limited color names [link](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp). (around 140) 
3: User can search for only 140 color names (I guess). but there would be millions of combinations of colors  
4: One thing is sure, the exact color could not be returned in every case. 
5: So, how could the nearest colors be returned.

Comment: Hello, if my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon else feel free to ask further questions :) [What should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the closest match for a given color value might be tricky for Firestore. If you just want your user the select a color name from the list, (red, blue, green etc.) you can convert the value you are getting from Vision to a name and store that in the firestore document. That way you can query against a string value. If you have multiple color values you can store them in an array as well and query against the array values.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hex-color-to-color-name

Comment: There would be many combinations of colors. Only storing limited colors would not help because the possibility of being red in an image is quite rare. On an average day not everyone will be using red color, it must be some variant, darker, lighter etc.

Comment: This depends on the context of your work. A car or a tshirt can be dark red or light green. After getting the hex from the Vision API, you can convert it to the closest color name. These are the variant of color "red" in this example. So a user can search for the red cars and see the dark red one. Combinations of other colors would also work. However, if you want to differentiate the search between light red and dark red, this would not be ideal in your context.

Comment: How can I convert color into its variants? If that's possible then I can store that into a document and can be returned upon user search request!

Comment: I haven’t used the library that I shared above but it should return the closest color name. So if you feed it with a hex value(lets assume it is dark red) it will return red. There might be another library for more detailed results.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has two different databases namely [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore). I'm not sure which one are you using but in my opinion Firestore would be ideal.

Let's break this down in small steps:

**1. Using Cloud Vision API and adding to Firestore:**

You can process your images using the Cloud Vision API in your cloud functions, server or wherever your are using it and then add the data to Firestore.

```
//... process image
const colors = ["FF0000", "00FF00", "0000FF"]
// Assume colors is an array of hex codes of colors found in that image
// Add the image data in Firestore

await admin.firestore().collection("images").add({
  path: "path/in/storage",
  colors,
  ...otherMetaData
})
```

Make sure you add the colors array and the path or URL of that image (just an identifier to locate images from where you are storing them).

**2. Querying images which has colors entered by user:**

```
// Add your color picker 
const color = "FF0000" // color chosen by the user

// Make a query to Firestore from client
const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection("images").where("colors", "array-contains", color).get()

const images = snapshot.docs.map((img) => img.path)
```

Now you have an array of URLs of images which contains the color chosen by the user. You can similarly add RGBA or HSL values.

Comment: The user would be searching as a text for colors, how can this be handled?

Comment: @PingPong you would have to fetch the HEX from your react color picker component

Comment: Can we search for nearest colors if we have hex value or any variant of color

Comment: @PingPong that's not possible by direct queries. I'm not sure if converting the HEX to decimal then storing in database and then querying using greater than or less than operators upto a limit may help.